Suggestion for upgrading from Xamarin Forms for Android App
I have an Android application that is currently part of a multiplatform solution. I've been using Xamarin Forms in it.
Recently I've had to update the application to .Net 8 to support the newer version of Android.
In my research I've seen that Xamarin Forms is no longer supported and it cannot be used for .Net 8 or the newer versions of Android. A lot of what I'm seeing is recommending .Net MAUI.
However it appears to me that MAUI is not going to be supported/useful for the long term. My research is also finding a lot of conflicting info about all the options and I'm unsure of what to go with.
Is there any other options that would be suggested to utilize going forward for the long term (at least 2-3 years)?
If it helps, the Android application is the main focus, cross platform is not necessary.
Thank you for the help in advance. I am fairly new-ish and inexperienced in application development

It's recommended to update the Xamarin. Forms project to .NET MAUI.
.NET MAUI is open-source and is the evolution of Xamarin.Forms, extended from mobile to desktop scenarios, with UI controls rebuilt from the ground up for performance and extensibility.
It will be supported for a long time.
